# How to convert a pdf file into jpeg/png with GhostScript with PHP

Tags: php, imagemagick, ghostscript

Im using PHP to generate a PDF report and finally im converting the generated PDF into image and saving that as preview, Im using imagemagick currently, but the converted image is not in better quality, so I need a way where I can convert a PDF into high resoluted image.

I saw some articles about ghostscript(I dont have any exp with it) and just started it, can some one suggest me the better way? or the procedure with Ghostscript if it is the right one?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this comment on the manual - see if that will work.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimageresolution.php#96182